# Adding Days To C# Nullable DateTime Object Not Performing In While Loop

Tags: c#, loops, datetime, for-loop, nullable

I am writing some production code here, and having to add some code of my own design on top of code that is already a bit problematic. I have a loop that helps calculate dates based on a certain pay period.

The problem I am encountering is that my `Nullable DateTime` objects are not changing at all when having values added to them by using the `DateTime?.Value.AddDays()` function call. When  I run through this code, the `nextPayDate` object and its value stay the same even though I add to it during my loop. Said behavior is not useful and also is creating an endless loop. Thoughts?

```
public static List<DateTime?> GetLPSPaymentDates(Applicant applicant, int loanTermType, DateTime deliveryConfirmationDate)
{

    if (applicant == null)
    {
        throw new Exception("The applicant you are wanting to set an LPS for is null");
    }

    DateTime? firstPaymentDate = DateTime.Today;
    DateTime? secondPaymentDate = DateTime.Today;
    DateTime? lastPayDate = applicant.MainEmployer.LastPayDate;
    DateTime? nextPayDate = applicant.MainEmployer.NextPayDate;

    DateTime? earliestPossiblePaymentDate =   deliveryConfirmationDate.AddDays(10);

    int daysToAdd = 0;
    if (lastPayDate != null && nextPayDate != null)
    {
        var tempDate = nextPayDate;
        while (tempDate.Value <= earliestPossiblePaymentDate.Value)
        {
            daysToAdd =     IncrementPaymentDateByTermType((TermTypes)loanTermType);
            nextPayDate.Value.AddDays(daysToAdd);
            firstPaymentDate.Value.AddDays(daysToAdd);
        }
        if (firstPaymentDate == DateTime.Today)
        {
            firstPaymentDate = nextPayDate;
        }
        secondPaymentDate = firstPaymentDate.Value.AddDays(daysToAdd); 
    }
    else
    {
        throw new Exception("Could not find applicant's last or next pay date.");
    }

    List<DateTime?> firstAndSecondDates = new List<DateTime?>()
    {
        firstPaymentDate,
        secondPaymentDate
    };

    return firstAndSecondDates;

}

public static int IncrementPaymentDateByTermType(TermTypes termType)
{
    int numberOfDaysToAdd;

    switch (termType)
    {
        case TermTypes.BiWeekly:
            numberOfDaysToAdd = 14; 
            break;
        case TermTypes.Weekly:
            numberOfDaysToAdd = 7;
            break;
        default:
            numberOfDaysToAdd = 1;
            break;
    }
    return numberOfDaysToAdd;
}
```

Comment: `nextPayDate.Value.AddDays(daysToAdd);`  AddDays returns a NEW DateTime with the new value.  Intellisense: `Returns a new System.DateTime that adds the specified number of days to the value of this instance.`

Comment: You have to hold this in a variable `nextPayDate.Value.AddDays(daysToAdd);` the original date is not changed.

Comment: nullable DateTimes have far fewer avilaable functions and behave in manners differently than DateTime. If you are working against a DB, a null value for a DateTime field will yield a year of 1000. You can use regular DateTime and test for DateTime.Year>2000 if you want to use DateTime instead of working with nullable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AddDays returns a new object as the result instead of updating the existing object.  Try:

```
daysToAdd = IncrementPaymentDateByTermType((TermTypes)loanTermType);
nextPayDate = nextPayDate.Value.AddDays(daysToAdd);
firstPaymentDate = firstPaymentDate.Value.AddDays(daysToAdd);
```

Answer (score 0):

Didn't test it, but this should help (given your while loop logic is correct)

```
while (tempDate.Value <= earliestPossiblePaymentDate.Value)
{
    daysToAdd = IncrementPaymentDateByTermType((TermTypes)loanTermType);
    tempDate = nextPayDate.Value.AddDays(daysToAdd); // <<= updating tempDate
    firstPaymentDate.Value.AddDays(daysToAdd);
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much to all who helped get this question answered; in the end, you all were right. I was making the simple mistake of not actually storing the changed value into a variable that is trackable and tangible. The loop logic is correct and everything is working now. Thanks peeps. Just so you all know, I've up voted both answers here. Thanks to those who commented as well.

Comment: @shimmerwoof please accept an answer if it solved your problem.